# we consider strings of characters, where each character is an element of {a, b, c}. Such a string is called awesome

Tags: combinatorics

$ :$ We consider strings of characters, where each character is an
element of $\{ a , b , c \} .$ Such a string is called awesome, if it does not contain the substring ab
and does not contain the substring ba. For any integer $n \geq 1 ,$ let

\begin{array} { l } { \text { 1. Sn denote the number of awesome strings of length } n } \\ { \text { 2. } A _ { n } \text { denote the number of awesome strings of length } n \text { that start with } a \text { , } } \end{array}

3. $B _ { n }$ denote the number of awesome strings of length $n$ that start with $b$
4. $C _ { n }$ denote the number of awesome strings of length $n$ that start with $c$

$\bullet$ Determine $S _ { 1 }$ and $S _ { 2 }$

$\bullet$ Let $n \geq 1$ be an integer. Express $S _ { n }$ in terms of $A _ { n } , B _ { n } ,$ and $C _ { n }$ .

$\bullet$ Let $n \geq 2$ be an integer. Express $C _ { n }$ in terms of $S _ { n - 1 }$ .

$\bullet$ Let $n \geq 2$ be an integer. Prove that

$S _ { n } = \left( S _ { n - 1 } - B _ { n - 1 } \right) + \left( S _ { n - 1 } - A _ { n - 1 } \right) + S _ { n - 1 }$

$\begin{aligned} \bullet \text { Let } n \geq 3 \text { be an integer. Prove that } \\ & S _ { n } = 2 \cdot S _ { n - 1 } + S _ { n - 2 } \end{aligned}$

Prove that for every integer $n \geq 1$

$S _ { n } = \frac { 1 } { 2 } ( 1 + \sqrt { 2 } ) ^ { n + 1 } + \frac { 1 } { 2 } ( 1 - \sqrt { 2 } ) ^ { n + 1 }$

Hint: What are the solutions of the equation $x ^ { 2 } = 2 x + 1 ?$ Using these solutions will
simplify the proof.

My Solutions

(a)

(i)

$S _ { 1 } = 3$ $\quad \quad$ ($1$ slot $3$ choices)

(ii)

$s _ { 2 } = 3 \times 3 = 9$ $\quad \quad$ ($2$ slots $3$ choices)

(b)

$S _ { n } = A _ { n } + B _ { n } + C _ { n }$ $\quad \quad$ (string must start with a,b,c)

(c)

$C _ { n } = 1 \times S _ { n - 1 } = S _ { n - 1 }$

(d)

since $ \quad A _ { n } = S _ { n - 1 } - B _ { n - 1 }$ $\quad \quad$ (no string ab)

and $ \quad B _ { n } = S _ { n - 1 } - A _ { n - 1 }$ $\quad \quad$ (no string ba)

from (b) $ \quad S _ { n } = A _ { n } + B _ { n } + C _ { n }$

$= \left( S _ { n - 1 } - B _ { n - 1 } \right) + \left( S _ { n - 1 } - A _ { n - 1 } \right) + C _ { n }$

$= \left( s _ { n - 1 } - B _ { n - 1 } \right) + \left( s _ { n - 1 } - A _ { n - 1 } \right) + S _ { n - 1 }\quad \quad \because C _ { n } = S _ { n - 1 }$ from (c)

(e)

from (b) $S _ { n } = A _ { n } + B _ { n } + C _ { n }$

$\Rightarrow S _ { n - 1 } = A _ { n - 1 } + B _ { n - 1 } + C _ { n - 1 }$

$S _ { n } = \left( S _ { n - 1 } - B _ { n - 1 } \right) + \left( S _ { n - 1 } - A _ { n - 1 } \right) + S _ { n - 1 }$

from (e) $S _ { n } = [ A _ { n - 1 } + B _ { n - 1 } + C _ { n - 1 } - B _ { n - 1 }] + [ A _ { n - 1 } + B _ { n - 1 } + C _ { n - 1 } - A _ { n - 1 } ] + S _ { n - 1 }$

$S _ { n } = \left( A _ { n - 1 } + C _ { n - 1 } \right) + \left( B _ { n - 1 } + C _ { n - 1 } \right) + S _ { n - 1 }$

$= A _ { n - 1 } + C _ { n - 1 } + B _ { n - 1 } + C _ { n - 1} + S _ { n - 1 }$

$= \left( A _ { n - 1 } + B _ { n - 1 } + C _ { n - 1 } \right) + S _ { n - 1 } + C _ { n - 1 }$

from $ S _ { n } = A _ { n } + B _ { n } + C _ { n } \quad and C _ { n } = S _ { n - 1 }$

$S _ { n } = S _ { n - 1 } + S _ { n - 1 } + S _ { n - 2 }$

$S _ { n } = 2 \cdot S _ { n - 1 } + S _ { n - 2 }$

(f)

Since $S _ { n } = 2 \cdot S _ { n - 1 } + S _ { n - 2 }$

$\frac { S _ { n } } { S _ { n - 2 } } = 2 \frac { S _ { n - 1 } } { S _ { n - 2 } } + S _ { n - 2 }$

$x ^ { 2 } = 2 x + 1$

$x = \frac { - ( - 2 ) \pm \sqrt { ( - 2 ) ^ { 2 } - 4 ( 1 )(-1 ) } } { 2 ( 1 ) }$

$= \frac { 2 \pm \sqrt { 8 } } { 2 }$

$1 + \sqrt { 2 }$ or $1 - \sqrt { 2 }$

Question

I'm not sure if my proof are mathematically correct and I'm stuck on how to use the solutions of $x ^ { 2 } = 2 x + 1$ to get $S _ { n } = \frac { 1 } { 2 } ( 1 + \sqrt { 2 } ) ^ { n + 1 } + \frac { 1 } { 2 } ( 1 - \sqrt { 2 } ) ^ { n + 1 }$

Clearly we are taking roots but the answer is like a solution to an auxillary equation . Any assistance would be great appreciated.

Comment: (a ii): $S_2 = |\{a,b,c\}\times\{a,b,c\}\setminus\{(a,b),(b,a)\}| = 3^2-2 = 7$.

Comment: (e): $$S_{n}=\left(S_{n-1}-B_{n-1}\right)+\left(S_{n-1 }-A_{n-1}\right)+S_{n-1}=2S_{n-1}+\left(S_{n-1}-A_{n-1}-B_{n-1}\right)=2S_{n-1}+C_{n-1}=2S_{n-1}+S_{n-2}$$

Comment: Sorry how is your (e) different from my (e) 

P.S. thanks for the correction on (a)(ii) forgot about the restriction

Comment: It's not "different", it's maybe shorter. :-)

Comment: Knowing (e), you could prove the formula using "complete induction".

Comment: It most certainly is shorter , I just wanted to make sure mine was wrong :) thanks

Comment: This formula $S _ { n } = \frac { 1 } { 2 } ( 1 + \sqrt { 2 } ) ^ { n + 1 } + \frac { 1 } { 2 } ( 1 - \sqrt { 2 } ) ^ { n + 1 }$ with induction ?

Comment: does the division I made in (f) make sense , to end up with $x ^ { 2 } = 2 x + 1$?

Comment: Yes, that's how I would do it. If you have a different proof for the formula for the Fibonacci numbers, you can for sure apply the same principle here. (I mean the induction, not the division)